# Can't change website Title on wordpress

Tags: php, urls, seo

Even if the configs of my wordpress are set up correctly (I believe), I can't seen to change the title that appears on the browser tab AND when I share my link.

I even got to change the browser title tab using All In One SEO Pack (Yoast was no help), but when I share my url on Whatsapp, Facebook or paste it anywhere, it is converted to the name of the theme and not of my website.

The name of my site is appropriately setup on WP configs, but even so, the name of the template remains.

Any idea on how I can solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `header.php` file, and see if the `<title>` attribute isn't fixed to the the Theme's name.

Also, if the All in One SEO Pack did modify it on the browser, other services (like facebook) cache the metadata from urls shared, and you would need to manually flush them. (Facebook for instance has this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

*Sorry no rep to make a comment*

Answer (score 0):

A quick check to see if your theme is causing the problem is to quickly change the theme to one of the WP 20xx themes and see if that fixes the problem. (That can be problematic on 'live' and active sites.)

Also, check if your Theme's Customization screens have a setting whether to display the site's title.